# colnames() in 2 line / set a table with 2 line header

Tags: html, r, dataframe, datatable, datatables

I have a data frame, assuming as below, and I want to see two line in the header.

```
head(iris)
colnames(iris) <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length","Petal.Width", " This is Species but I want to assign here 2 line very long name ")
head(iris)
```

many thanks in advance,

Comment: `head(iris, 2)`